# How to calculate number of days until weekend or day off in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, running-count

I have pandas dataframe with a non-continuous date index (missing are weekends and holidays). I want to add column which would contain number of days until next day off.

Here is code generating example dataframe with desired values in *till_day_off* column:

```py
import pandas as pd
​
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start="2022-06-06", periods=15))
df["day_of_week"] = df.index.dayofweek   # adding column with number of day in a week
df = df[(df.day_of_week < 5)]   # remove weekends
df = df.drop(index="2022-06-15")   # remove Wednesday in second week
df["till_day_off"] = [5,4,3,2,1,2,1,2,1,1] # desired values, end of column is treated as day off
```

Resulting dataframe:

|  | day_of_week | till_day_off |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-06 | 0 | 5 |
| 2022-06-07 | 1 | 4 |
| 2022-06-08 | 2 | 3 |
| 2022-06-09 | 3 | 2 |
| 2022-06-10 | 4 | 1 |
| 2022-06-13 | 0 | 2 |
| 2022-06-14 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-06-16 | 3 | 2 |
| 2022-06-17 | 4 | 1 |
| 2022-06-20 | 0 | 1 |

Real dataframe has over 7_000 rows so obviously I am trying to avoid iteration over rows. Any idea how to tackle the issue?

Comment: So how do you know what you're days off are supposed to be?

Comment: Days off are missing from dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a sorted input (if not, sort it by days), you can use a mask to identify consecutive days and use it to group them and compute a cumcount:

```
mask = (-df.index.to_series().diff(-1)).eq('1d').iloc[::-1]
# reversing the Series to count until (not since) the value

df['till_day_off'] = mask.groupby((~mask).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
```

output:

```
            day_of_week  till_day_off
2022-06-06            0             5
2022-06-07            1             4
2022-06-08            2             3
2022-06-09            3             2
2022-06-10            4             1
2022-06-13            0             2
2022-06-14            1             1
2022-06-16            3             2
2022-06-17            4             1
2022-06-20            0             1
```

intermediates:

```
mask

2022-06-20    False
2022-06-17    False
2022-06-16     True
2022-06-14    False
2022-06-13     True
2022-06-10    False
2022-06-09     True
2022-06-08     True
2022-06-07     True
2022-06-06     True
dtype: bool

(~mask).cumsum()

2022-06-20    1
2022-06-17    2
2022-06-16    2
2022-06-14    3
2022-06-13    3
2022-06-10    4
2022-06-09    4
2022-06-08    4
2022-06-07    4
2022-06-06    4
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a DataFrame of the missing dates, then use a `merge_asof` to match with the closest one in the future and calculate the time until that day off.

Here I assume days off are just missing dates, but this extends to the case where you have an explicit list of dates you want to use.

```
import pandas as pd

# DataFrame of missing dates, e.g. days off.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'day_off': pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max()+pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1), freq='D')})
df1 = df1[~df1['day_off'].isin(df.index)]

df = pd.merge_asof(df, df1, left_index=True, right_on='day_off', direction='forward')
df['till_day_off'] = (df['day_off'] - df.index).dt.days
```

---

```
print(df)

            day_of_week    day_off  till_day_off
2022-06-06            0 2022-06-11             5
2022-06-07            1 2022-06-11             4
2022-06-08            2 2022-06-11             3
2022-06-09            3 2022-06-11             2
2022-06-10            4 2022-06-11             1
2022-06-13            0 2022-06-15             2
2022-06-14            1 2022-06-15             1
2022-06-16            3 2022-06-18             2
2022-06-17            4 2022-06-18             1
2022-06-20            0 2022-06-21             1
```